# Send signal with data from bash script

Tags: bash, signals

I want to send a signal to a process including data (int) from a bash script. I know how to do that from a C program but I didn't find the way if exists from a script.

**Note :** Pipe isn't an option

Comment: ?? How do you do that from C? The kill command have this signature: `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);` There's no space for an integer, just the PID of the process being signaled and the signal itself. In fact, I'm not aware you can send a signal that carries an associated integer.

Comment: In fact you can carry an integer or a pointer to a shared memory block. The problem is that you can't know if it's a pointer or an integer. [Take a look here](https://www.engineersgarage.com/how-to-send-value-between-processes-using-signal-part-24-38/)

Comment: My question stands: how do you send a signal that carries some information in C?

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I posted. At the end of the page you will find some source code that explains how to do it. I don't do anything more.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of following links, as they get broken with time and then the questions and answers become unintelligible. It's better practice to put all relevant information in the question, not having to rely on external resources.

Comment: Either case, the following answer of the sister-site StackExchange may be of your interest: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232980/sending-sigaction-sigqueue-through-shell

In short, there's no way, but you can solve it with a small C program that allows you interface with `bash`. The relevant command `sigqueue` does not seem to have an already-ready interface for `bash`.

Comment: Ok for the external references. As you can see I'm a bit new and need to learn more.